# How to force using multicore in QThread with OpenMP function

Tags: c++, qt, pthreads, openmp, qthread

I have a function which is very parallelized in OpenMP, when launched from a simple console executable it saturates every core of the machine and returns the result linearly faster in the number of processors.

```
void updateStateWithAParallelAlgorithm()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    {
    // do parallel things, update positions of particles in a physics simulation
    }
}
```

Now this function is also used inside a QThread in my Qt program. The problem is that I have to update screen positions of the particles every after a call of `updateStateWithAParallelAlgorithm()` function.

When launched inside my Qt main program, I see no improvement in speed of the algorithm and the 8 cores of my processor are not saturated.

I would rather believe that I should see a peak-pause behaviour on the graph of CPU usage, but this doesn't happen.

Now, I'm giving you more informations.

```
class MyComputationThread :  public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // some methods
    // some variables
    void doComputation()
    { 

        this->setPriority(QThread::HighestPriority);

        #ifdef Q_WS_X11
          int s;
          cpu_set_t cpuset;
          CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
          CPU_SET(1, &cpuset);
          s = pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
          if (s != 0) {
            perror("pthread_getaffinity_np");
          }
        #endif

        updateStateWithAParallelAlgorithm();
    }
}
```

I would like to understand how my thread `MyComputationThread` class can exploit the multicore, without being constraint to only one CPU as in the statement of `pthread_set_affinity_np`.

Comment: Maybe pthread_setaffinity_np prevents using additional cores. Why do you need this call?

Comment: This was a part of code I didn't want to modify for obscure reasons...it's not mine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` manual page:

> A new thread created by `pthread_create(3)` inherits a copy of its creator's CPU affinity mask.

You are limiting the particular `MyComputationThread` instance to run on a single core only and thus are also limiting all threads spawned by the OpenMP run-time to also run on the same core. You should either remove the call to `pthread_setaffinity_np()` or move the call to `updateStateWithAParallelAlgorithm()` *before* the part that sets the affinity.

Comment: Yes! This is the solution, I removed that infamous part of code both in the MainWindow class and in mythread class, now the algorithm is parallelized correctly!